# Git server without requiring /directory/where/git/repos/are/?

Tags: git

I have a git repo on my server and when I go to add a remote I use

`git remote add origin git@gitserver:/opt/git/project.git`

Or something like that. I am wondering how can I get rid of the `/opt/git/` and just make it

`git@server.com:project.git`

Comment: Make `/opt/git` the home directory for the `git` user on `gitserver`? Alternatively, put `project.git` in `/home/git`, or whatever the current home directory for the `git` user is...

Comment: I think you should add that as an answer, @twalberg

Comment: Done. It seemed a bit too simple, so I posted it as a comment first, thinking there might be more to it than that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `/opt/git` the home directory for the `git` user on `gitserver`? Alternatively, put `project.git` in `/home/git`, or whatever the current home directory for the `git` user is...